# navigation controller is nil when qr scan callback comes

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a implementation of qr scanner in `ControllerA` it is recieving callbacks of scanned data. `QRScanner` is my custom class

```
extension QRScanner : AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            self.delegate?.scannedData(QRScannerErrorCode.NoData.rawValue)
            return
        }

        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {
            self.stopSession()
            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                if (validateCode!(metadataObj.stringValue!)) {
                    self.delegate!.scannedData(metadataObj.stringValue!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am recieving callback to `Controller A` from above.

```
extension ControllerA : QRScannerDelegate {
    func scannedData(_ scannedString: String) {

        if(validateData(scannedString: scannedString)) {
            self.scanResult!.action     = Action.SCAN
            self.scanResult!.result     = scannedString

            assert(self.delegate != nil)

            self.delegate!.result(result: self.scanResult!)
            print("Nav stack:) \(System.currentTimeMillis())")
            self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }

    func validateData(scannedString: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}

func stopSession() {

    assert(session != nil && session!.isRunning)

    self.session!.stopRunning()
}
```

With the flow of app I tested navigating to and fro from this Controller to another controller. And in between I scan qr code and my app crashes.
When I put logs then I found that navigationController is nil.

I know that qr scanner continously scan the image and call delegate. So for that I added `stopSession` when valid image is scanned but still I am getting back to back two scanned result just before crashing .

> I want to know why this is happening?

When I put `self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)` in the controller which invoked `ControllerA` then the app is not crashing.

Comment: can you show me the code to invoke the scanner.

Comment: Thats very big.. and i guess it will be irrelevent .

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is not added to a UINavigationController subclass, this is why self.navigationController is nil (Using '!' with a nil variable will crash, and this what happened for you)

I think that your scannedData function still being called after calling stopSession(), you have to add a flag (stopped for example) and add a test on that flag on your scannedData function.

Also i think that you need to change

```
self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
```

with

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

to avoid crashes.

Comment: No this could not be the issue. Bcz i had put a log which shows that navigation controller has two view controllers